# How to make only the LINK on top level Drop-down menu highlighted and trigger animation, not the whole Li class?

Tags: jquery, animation, drop-down-menu, highlight

I'm using a simple Jquery drop down menu, found here http://wabism.com/jquery-drop-down-menu-tutorial/

I just wanted to know how I can get the Link that triggers the menu to stay Highlighted while hovering over links within the drop-down. Also, make ONLY the LINK of the top-level menu trigger the animation NOT the whole li class...

Someone helped me fix up the code to disable animation repeats. So I replaced default Plugin code with this//

```
$('body').ready(function() {
$('.dropdown').hover(function() {
if ($(this).find('.sub_navigation').is(":visible")) {
$(this).find('.sub_navigation').slideUp();} else {
$(this).find('.sub_navigation').slideDown();}
});
});
```

Here is a fiddle// http://jsfiddle.net/tUYfw/90/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just wanted to know how I can get the Link that triggers the menu to stay Highlighted     while hovering over links within the drop-down.

```
.dropdown:hover > a {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Since the `.dropdown` list item encompasses the entire dropdown menu, it will always be hovered-over as long as the cursor is interacting with the dropdown. But we don't want the entire list item to have a grey background, just the link. So we use the immediate child selector to style the parent link.

> Also, make ONLY the LINK of the top-level menu trigger the animation NOT the whole li class...

That's a little more tricky, because the act of hovering over the entire parent list item is what allows the dropdown to stay open.

Why do you need only the link to activate the menu? If you explain your reasoning maybe we can suggest a better alternative.

Comment: I tried the "> a" and it worked thank you so much :)
As for the li class here is a screenshot of the navigation//
http://i45.tinypic.com/20zw900.png I just want only the link to trigger the menu because I have the width of the ul to 130px so there is space between the all of the navigation links. I don't want the viewer to roll over an empty black space and a menu slides down. I feel it will look better for the link to reveal the menu not the black space.. I am not good with vocabulary lol sorry for my poor explanation.

Comment: I'd need to see your code to help properly, but I suspect your CSS just needs to be modified.

Comment: Still need to see your code if you're still having a problem.

Comment: Hmm, I'm afraid you've stumped me on that one. I don't think it's possible without doing some pretty weird stuff with your markup. Can you just compromise and have the parent link stretch all the way across?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown a').bind('onmouseover',function() {
        $this = $(this).closest('.dropdown');
        $this.find('.sub_navigation').slideDown();
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/T6mhX/

http://api.jquery.com/closest

Comment: Same with the answer above, the menu drops when link is hovered but goes right back up when hovering over menu links.

Comment: Well, that's what "hover" does. Your problem is that you're absolutely-positioning the submenu OUTSIDE of the parent `li`. Under what conditions do you want the submenu to vanish again?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the selector to select the anchor tag, then modify the jQuery code to use the parentNode instead.

```
$('body').ready(function() {
    $('.dropdown a').hover(function() {
        if ($(this.parentNode).find('.sub_navigation').is(":visible")) {
            $(this.parentNode).find('.sub_navigation').slideUp();
        } else {
            $(this.parentNode).find('.sub_navigation').slideDown();
        }
    });
});​
```

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tUYfw/93/

Comment: When I use this, the menu ends up sliding right back up when I try to hover over menu links :/

Answer (score 0):

If all .dropdowns are equivalent, you can use first-child selector to do something with only the first one

```
$('.dropdown:first-child').hover(function() {...
```

http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/